# Passing an argument to a Controller from a Modal window

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

The Modal JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#submit').click(function (e) {
            var locked = '@ViewBag.Locked';
            if (locked) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#accountLocked').reveal();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The Popup Div

```
<div id="accountLocked" class="reveal-modal">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("EmailHelpDesk", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <h1>Account Locked</h1>
            <p>Please provide your email address and you'll be contacted shortly.</p><br/>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email"/>
            <input type="submit" id="submitEmail" name="submit"/>
        }
    </div>
```

The EmailHelpDesk ActionResult within the AccountController

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult EmailHelpDesk(string email)
    {
        var Email = email;
        return RedirectToAction("Create", "User");
    }
```

The code doesn't break on the Action and I don't understand why. Am I doing something wrong?

The modal pops up but the EmailHelpDesk method doesn't execute. On submit the modal just disappears and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution works as is. I was missing a closing curly bracket in the CSHTML page.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your line `var locked = '@ViewBag.Locked';` is to blame. What you're doing (assuming the value is false), is writing:

```
var locked = 'false';
```

Notice that it's a string. The string `"false"` is actually truthy. If you change it to:

```
var locked = @ViewBag.Locked;
```

then it will render as:

```
var locked = false;
```

Then I would expect it to work.

Comment: I have no problem getting the modal to popup. I am able to enter an email with the input and submit with the other input. However the breakpoint on the action doesn't break and modal just goes away.